# Count average with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a query which allows to categorize the average percentage for specific data per month.

Here's how my dataset presents itself:

| Date | Name | Group | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-21 | name1 | gr1 | 5.2 |
| 2022-01-22 | name1 | gr1 | 6.1 |
| 2022-01-26 | name1 | gr1 | 4.9 |
| 2022-02-01 | name1 | gr1 | 3.2 |
| 2022-02-03 | name1 | gr1 | 8.1 |
| 2022-01-22 | name2 | gr1 | 36.1 |
| 2022-01-25 | name2 | gr1 | 32.1 |
| 2022-02-10 | name2 | gr1 | 35.8 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

And here's what I want to obtain with my query (based on what I showed of the table):

| Month | <=25% | 25<_<=50% | 50<_<=75% | 75<_<=100% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 02 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

The result needs to:

- Be ordered by month
- Have the average use for each name counted and categorized

So far I know how to get the average of the `Percent` value per `Name`:

```
SELECT Name,
AVG(Percent) 
from `table`  
where Group = 'gr1' 
group by Name
```

and how to count iterations of `Percent` in the categories created for the query:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) as Month,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Percent <= 25 AND Group = 'gr1' THEN Name END) `_25`,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Percent > 25 AND Percent <= 50 AND Group = 'gr1' THEN Name END) `_50`,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Percent > 50 AND Percent <= 75 AND Group = 'gr1' THEN Name END) `_75`,
COUNT(CASE WHEN Percent > 75 AND Percent <= 100 AND Group = 'gr1' THEN Name END) `_100`,
FROM `table`
GROUP BY Month
ORDER BY Month
```

but this counts all iterations of every name where I want the average of those values.

I've been struggling to figure out how to combine the two queries or to create a new one that answers my need.

I'm working with the BigQuery service from Google Cloud

Comment: Note that Date in `GROUP BY Date` is referencing the base table column.

Comment: OK, so I need an alias to make sure I'm referencing the Month extraction

Comment: If your dbms supports that non-standard construction.

Comment: Can you update your post with the DBMS you're currently using?

Comment: Sure thing, I'm using BigQuery from GCP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query produces the needed result, based on your example. So basically this combines your 2 queries using subquery, where the subquery is responsible to calculate `AVG` grouped by `Name`, `Month` and `Group`, and the outer query is for `COUNT` and "categorization"

```
SELECT
    Month,
    COUNT(CASE
      WHEN avg <= 25 THEN Name
    END) AS _25,
    COUNT(CASE
      WHEN avg  > 25
       AND avg  <= 50 THEN Name
    END) AS _50,
    COUNT(CASE
      WHEN avg  > 50
       AND avg  <= 75 THEN Name
    END) AS _75,
    COUNT(CASE
      WHEN avg  > 75
       AND avg <= 100 THEN Name
    END) AS _100
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
          EXTRACT(MONTH from Date) AS Month,
          Name,
          AVG(Percent) AS avg
        FROM
          table1
        GROUP BY Month, Name, Group
        HAVING Group = 'gr1'
    ) AS namegr
  GROUP BY Month
```

This is the result:

| Month | _25 | _50 | _75 | _100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

See also Fiddle (BUT on MySql) - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16c5882/9

Comment: Thanks for the help, didn't expect to be able to put a subquery in the `FROM` in order to combine the two queries

Comment: Always welcome @Hibann

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to Group By ***Month*** and each ***Name***

```
SELECT CONCAT(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date), ', ', Name) AS DateAndName, 
CASE
    WHEN AVG(Percent) <= 25 THEN '1'
    ELSE '0'
END AS '<=25%',
CASE
    WHEN AVG(Percent) > 25 AND AVG(Percent) <= 50 THEN '1'
    ELSE '0'
END AS '25<_<=50%',
CASE
    WHEN AVG(Percent) > 50 AND AVG(Percent) <= 75 THEN '1'
    ELSE '0'
END AS '50<_<=75%',
CASE
    WHEN AVG(Percent) > 75 AND AVG(Percent) <= 100 THEN '1'
    ELSE '0'
END AS '75<_<=100%'
from DataTable /*change to your table name*/
group by EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date), Name
order by DateAndName
```

It gives the following result:

| DateAndName | <=25% | 25<_<=50% | 50<_<=75% | 75<_<=100% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1, name1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1, name2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2, name1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2, name2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |